# How to properly author or create a JQuery plugin that supports HTML data-*attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am currently creating a JQuery Plugin that support data-attributes for defining options. I scoured the internet for sources on how to propery do it, but cannot find any.

**What I have done so far:**

**HTML:**

```
 <table id="myTable" data-columns='[{ "header": "Header1" },
                { "header": "Header2" },
                { "header": "Header3" }]'>
    </table>
```

**Plugin:**

```
 $.fn.myPlugin = function () {
        columns:""

    }
    var self = $(this)
    var foo = self.data("columns")

    //..some code to create columns
```

**Plugin Usage:**

```
$("#myTable").myPlugin()
```

Comment: You don't have to do anything; jQuery already understands the attributes, and will in fact parse them for you. That `self.data()` call will return an array of objects.

Comment: Also, in a *plugin* (unlike a callback to a jQuery method), you don't have to write `$(this)`, because `this` will point to the jQuery object and not an individual element. In fact, the standard practice for a plugin that could operate meaningfully on more than one matched element in the jQuery object should use a `.each()` loop, and also of course return the jQuery object as its result so that it can be used in a call chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal jQuery plugin based on your question.

```js
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function () {
        this.filter('table').each(function() {
            var container = $(this);
            var data = container.data('columns');
            var html = '<tr>'
               + data.map(obj => '<th>' + obj.header + '</th>').join('')
               + '</tr>';
            console.log('html: '+html);
            container.append(html);
        });
        return this;
    }
}( jQuery ));

$('#myTable').myPlugin()
```

```css
#myTable th {
  border: 1px gray solid;
  padding: 1px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" data-columns='[{ "header": "Header1" },
    { "header": "Header2" },
    { "header": "Header3" }]'>
  </table>
```

Note the `.filter('table')`, which makes sure the code is only applied to tables.